# How can I run multiple SSRS reports on multiple threads

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, reporting-services

I have about 100 linked reports that are run on a weekly and monthly basis.  I have put together a c# console that dynamically creates the Report Server folders for a specific period from a db table and creates linked SSRS reports from a db table.  These reports run fine but each report is run one at a time in a foreach loop which is fine if you run them overnight but sometimes these reports fail (for whatever reason) and the failed reports are marked as such in the DB.

My question is:
How can I run (for example ) 10 reports on a thread and run each thread at the same time – 10 threads running at the same time so the time to run all reports should be much quicker. This should take a fraction of the time to re-run any failed reports on a Monday. Is this even possible?

In my c# console I am using ReportingService2010 to create my linked reports:

```
ReportingService2010.CreateLinkedItem(linkedReport, folder, existingReportPath, props);

ReportingService2010.SetExecutionOptions(reportPath, "Snapshot", new NoSchedule());

ReportingService2010.SetItemHistoryOptions(reportPath, true, true, new NoSchedule());

ReportingService2010.UpdateItemExecutionSnapshot(reportPath);
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: You realise SSRS has a feature where you can schedule reports to run? There does not appear to be a good reason for running them this way.

Comment: Can you dynamically create the report server folders and create linked reports via a schedule?  For each week/month we need to create a folder structure with a new processing period so our users can look at historic data for any given time.

Comment: report history can be achieved with snapshots. perhaps a grouping or any custom listing of snapshots is possible. anyway your whole process would be greatly improved just relying upon snapshots: if you run snapshots the task you have to accomplish is the 'simple' download of the most recent snapshot for each report to store it in the appropriate folder.

Comment: Thank for getting back to me Ben and Paulo.  We are creating report history at the moment.  B creating a linked report, we are creating a snapshot.  The snapshot is created within a folder for a particular week, say 201401.  The following week we create the same report, different date as a snapshot and that gets created in folder 201402.  We are creating approx 100 reports and running one at a time is no efficient. I was hoping to find a way to create 10 reports on a thread and run multiple threads.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward solution is: create several C# console clients that share all the report generation (as if several clients were accessing the available reports concurrently). In this way you know for sure that the report generation is executed in batches. And that's it, because you cannot force SSRS server to process a certain number of reports at the same time. It will deal with its workload regardless how do you request the report generation.

Nonetheless, I believe this is a wrong approach.

You have to take in account that SSRS will process concurrently as many reports as it wants, and even if those reports are requested and processed at the same time, the SQL Server engine will process (again) the workload as it thinks it should do. All this means that executing concurrently all your reports (or in batches of N reports) won't assure you that the overall amount of time is going to be smaller. Another thing to take in account is that rendering the reports can take a great percentage of the total execution time (sometimes much more than executing all the sql queries), and this makes a heavy use of CPU.

The right approach, in the other hand, would be create a Data Warehouse that holds all that historical data (which would be purely DB engine process), and the reports (that should use date parameters) are only a way to access the data already stored in the Data Warehouse.

Anyway, I understand that creating a DW is a big project and you're looking for an easier solution. For that, you would need to identify where's the bottleneck (sql engine, ssrs rendering,...) and try to balance or increase your resources (if possible) to release that bottleneck.

Possibly is not the answer you need but could save you some time trying to develop a solution with little or no impact in your total processing time.